# Drupal 7: change "read more" on content type teaser

Tags: drupal-7, teaser

In a teaser of a content type, how do you change the text for the "read more" link button?

Answer (score 1):

Override the node output by placing this code in your theme's template.php file (replacing with `YourThemeName`, `YourContentType` and `NewReadMoreText` with your theme name and desired read more text).

**[Source](http://www.dreamleaf.co.uk/drupal/drupal-7-custom-read-more-links-content-type)**

```
<?php
// Preprocess variables for node.tpl.php.
function YourThemeName_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Let's get that read more link out of the generated links variable!
  unset($variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']);

  // Now let's put it back as it's own variable! So it's actually versatile!
  if ($variables['type'] == 'YourContentType') {
  $variables['newreadmore'] = t('<span class="YourContentTypereadmore"> <a href="!title">NewReadMoreText</a> </span>',
      array('!title' => $variables['node_url'],)
   );
  } else {
      $variables['newreadmore'] = t('<span class="newreadmore"> <a href="!title">Read More </a> </span>',
      array('!title' => $variables['node_url'],)
   );
  }

  $variables['title_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'node-title';
}
?>
```

Comment: That was the basic fix. What I did was just go to my www dir and grep -r "Read more" and for me it was located in modules/node/node.module

Then I made a copy of the file and changed it in there to "Load more" for my needs:

if ($view_mode == 'teaser') {
$node_title_stripped = strip_tags($node->title);
$links['node-readmore'] = array(
'title' => t('Load more<span class="element-invisible"> about @title</span>', array('@title' => $node_title_stripped)),
'href' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
'html' => TRUE,
'attributes' => array('rel' => 'tag', 'title' => $node_title_stripped),
);
}